# ionic build produces wrong apk filename

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

using ionic (v 1.0.0.-beta.13), cordova 4.0.0.  When I build for android, the name of the apk produced is "CordovaApp.apk", rather than ".apk", which it was "previously" (before some updates to ionic, cordova, and a delete/add of the android platform in my project).  The project name in my config.xml (in the project top level directory) is correct.

I can see the build.xml in my android platform directory specifies this, but this file is overwritten by the "ionic build" each time, so changing it there doesnt fix anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check following link, its the problem with Cordova version- 4

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-buid-apk-file-with-name-is-cordovaapp-apk-instead-of-widget-name/12255

Answer (score 0):

build.xml should contain apk name, to change that you should do:

```
android update project --name your_name --path
```